Symfony 7 doesn't send emails
I configured Symfony to send emails with AWS SES. I can send an email with php bin/console mailer:test --from from@example.net test@example.net, however, it doesn't work for in app emails. For example after registration I should receive an email but I don't, it's the same thing after I ask to reset the password.
How do we make things work?

What did you check the log?

@Bademeister I don't see any issues in the log. Here's the log: https://pastebin.com/3Qfk8bNA

@Raphael Log the debug of $this->transport->send($message) in your application. There can be many reasons why an email cannot be sent. From incorrect credentials to the recipient's mail server not accepting the email. The command mailer:test has no debug output.
